# Describing the kernel of a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{75}$ be the function defined by $\phi(n) = 27n \mod 75$, for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.

I'm trying to describe the kernel of $\phi$ as simply as possible and so far I got...

$\phi (n) = 27n\mod {75}$ $\\$
$\phi (n) = 0$ $\\$
$27n \mod 75 = 0$ $\\$
$27n = 75k$

From here i'm not sure how to finish this, i'm assuming $\mbox{Ker}( \phi ) \ne \frac{75}{27} \Bbb Z$ since that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are we assuming here that the binary operation for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{75}$ is addition?

Comment: Maybe try finding some concrete examples of elements in the kernel? From what you've done, it's clear that you need $27n \bmod 25 = 0$. Does $n = 5$ work? What else works? (Also, keep in mind that kernels of homomorphisms are subgroups of the domain.)

Comment: yes, the operation here is addition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you are looking for $$27n \equiv 0 \pmod{75}.$$
This is same as saying
$$9n \equiv 0 \pmod{25}.$$
$9$ has an inverse $14$ mod $25$. So multiply by $14$ on both sides to get
$$14(9n) \equiv 14(0) \pmod{25} \implies n \equiv 0 \pmod{25}.$$
Thus $n \in 25\Bbb{Z}=\{25k \, | \, k \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

**Note:** An intuitive way is to think that you want $27n$ to be $0$ in mod $75$. With $27n=3(9n)$, we already have a factor of $3$, so all we need is a factor of $25$ from $9n$ so that the whole thing will be a multiple of $75$. But $\gcd(9,25)=1$ so we can't anything from $9$, so $n$ has to supply the missing factor of $25$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the inverse of 9 to be 14?

Comment: @MattL. There are standard ways like Euclidean algorithm etc, to do that. But for this one I just observed that $9(11) \equiv 99 \pmod{25}$ so  $9(-11) \equiv -99  \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$. Thus $-11$ will be the inverse of $9$. But $-11 \equiv 14 \pmod{25}$. However **note** that we didn't really need the actual value of the inverse, just the existence could do the trick here.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall the definition of the kernel of a group homomorphism (in terms of the map you have given above):

If $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{75}$, given by $\phi(n) := 27n$ mod $75$, is a group homomorphism then the kernel of $\phi$, $Ker \phi$, is a subgroup of the **domain**.

So for your map $\phi$, figuring out how the kernel is defined should go something like this:

$Ker \phi :=$ {$n \in \mathbb{Z}| \phi(n) = 0$} = {$n \in \mathbb{Z}| 27n$ mod $75 =0$} =...

So, what you really need to find is all the $n$'s in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $27n$ mod $75 = 0$. Those $n$'s will be the elements of $Ker\phi$. I recommend the method given in the other answer for this post given by Anurag A.